# Creating widgets in GWT and using them in My existing website

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have just started learning GWT. My question is pretty simple:

If I create some widgets in GWT, lets say a Calculator widget and I want to use that widget in my existing PHP or JSP web app, then how can I do that ?

I am referring the book [GWT in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988231) for learning GWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link the *.nocache.js script files and add the history iFrame to the host PHP or JSP page.

Just have a div with a known id, lets say "marker" in your host HTML.

Add the Widget from your GWT application into the div as RootPanel.get( "marker" ).add( < your app widget > )

Comment: ok, should I copy that complete folder inside the war directory of the GWT project which contains various *.cache.* files along with the *.nocache.js file ?

and what about the GWT's standard theme CSS files ?

Comment: GWT compiler would have created a directory named after your GWT module in the war. The same dir contains amongst all the app resources a nocache.js file that you link in the host HTML. It is sufficient if you copy the < module name > folder relative to your host page and link to the nocache.js in it. That should work.